# website htaccess redirect conflict with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not too clued up on how htaccess file coding works, but I have got the following htaccess code in my root directory and it is responsible for redirecting from url.html to url.php:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)\.htm(l?)$ $1.php 


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ index.php [NC,R]
```

This code is important because all of the file names on the website have been changed over from 'html' to 'php' and I want all bookmarks and links made prior to the change over to remain valid.

The problem is, the above htaccess code seems to prevent the wordpress blog from opening, displaying the message "Too many redirects occurred when trying to open url".

Clearly there is some kind of redirect loop happening, but I cannot for the life of me work out exactly what the problem is.

In my wordpress directory (/blog) the htaccess file contains the usual for wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

When the above htaccess file is removed, the wordpress index file works fine, but because the wordpress htaccess file writes the rules for the post urls, they no longer work.

To summarise, I think there is a conflict between the two htaccess files (first one in the root directory, second one in the /blog directory) that is creating a redirect loop.

Any ideas as to how I might solve this will be very well received.

Thank you all in anticipation.

Comment: Have you tried splitting the folders, and resetting your apache's httpd.conf?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll be honest, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: you are in linux, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the Rewrite loop, you can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
#stop internal redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#Redirect /foo.html to /foo.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.html?$ /$1.php [L,R]
```

Replace both RedirectMatch and RewriteRule with the above Rules

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Just one final question. The first htaccess code in my original question redirected from 'htm' to 'php', but this one does not. How could I redirect from html and 'htm' to 'php'? Thanks.

Comment: Resolved: I changed the RewriteRule to: RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.htm(l?)$ /$1.php [L,R]